# Why am I getting kicked from an IRC channel in one OS (xp) but not in the other OS (7)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, irc, mirc

I got kicked from an IRC channel. I have Windows XP and now if I'm trying to get into this specific channel, I get inside but I get immediately kicked out.

I can come in again, and again get kicked out. It seems this is done automatically.

Now I have also installed, on another hard drive in the same computer Windows 7. On Windows7  I can get into this same channel and never kicked out! It's the same computer, but different operating system(separate Hard Drives).

How can it be?
Is the KICK command bias towards the operating system I got KICKed in? 
Please explain to me how this thing is happening.

PS:
I forgot to mention that it doesn't matter if i change my IP or my nickname, I continue to kicked out from this channel. Again, in windows 7 I can get in without a problem.

another thing that is good to mention is that i got kicked out when i was using windows XP, and not windows 7.
i think that it could happened also with windows 2000 and vista, so i dont bother the OS itself, but why it's acting differently with a different OS?

Comment: Are you using different nicks? Different IP addresses?

Comment: I guess, it depends on the user. I suggest you to try on the first system, with another user.
If that does not work, the IP of the first system is banned and your second system got another.

Comment: i forget to mention that even if i change my IP(it can be done in my connection with disconnect, and connect again of the router) i got kicked again.  also it doesn't matter what nick i have. in XP i get kicked all the time no matter what is my IP or what is my nick

Comment: Who is this Nick fellow everyone is talking about???

Comment: Kyle, you have made me laugh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've been akicked based on your username. In IRC, modes and bans and such are generally* done by matching a string to a hostmask, so if they've set akick (Automatic Kick) to kick:

```
*!usernameXP@*.host.net
```

and your hostmask is:

```
nick!usernameXP@127.0.0.01-host.net
```

then when you connect via your client in XP, it will match. But your client in Windows 7 is not configured the same way, and may have a different username:

```
nick!differentUserName7@127.0.0.1-host.net
```

This will not match, and you will not be automatically kicked. The good news is that you can configure your username string to be just about anything you want, the bad news is that it's very very easy for an operator to ban you again, this time replacing your username with a wildcard.

*by generally I mean universally, however some things such as access rights are tied to accounts, rather than hostmasks

Comment: thanks for your explanation :-), but please see my P.S. section in my post, in which i say that it doesn't matter what is my user name(or IP) and i get kicked right away i get into channel, in win XP. this is not the situation in win 7, which in there i have no problem to get in.

Comment: I think Phoshi is right on the money here.  An easy way to see if he is correct is to do a "//whois $me" without quotes in the server window of mIRC on each computer (when connected).  If the hostmasks are different, that would explain why you get booted from one and not from the other.

Comment: @moshe; There are three parts to your hostmask - you mentioned you change your nickname and IP address, **not** your username. The IRC protocol does not give even client information away, never mind OS information, and bans are based entirely on your hostmask string.

Comment: @Phoshi OK, so i understand i didnt understand you :-). how can i check if i have a different username in xp and 7 OSes? thanks! :-)

Comment: @kez thanks for your answer, but how do i get into the Server windows in mirc?

Comment: @moshe; /whois yourself from each OS, see what comes back. I also believe re:@kez that the server window pops up automatically, but it's been a while since I've used mIRC.